# AJAX and PHP after page refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to a PHP script that takes a long time to run. Now, assume it takes 20 minutes to run. Also assume that I either refreshed or closed then opened the web page that intiated the call. My questions are:

1. Does my PHP scrip stop running?
2. If it keeps running, how can I force a response back to the page after it was refreshed?

Thanks.

********************* UPDATE ***************************

Some are asking why I have a script that takes a long time. I think it is my fault of not explaining the following:

a. This script is only available to site admins, and is not available to the general public

b. This script will perform some heavy lifting, such as data manipulation and database related stuff, and will require a long time to run

c. I am using AJAX so that I could still return to the main page, with a spinner showing that the script is running, while the script actually runs in the back end, and the call back function will remove the spinner and display a message of either success/failure status.

Comment: "20 minutes" seriously ??

Comment: On a complete separate note, you need to know that by default PHP will lock session for the incoming request and thus other requests of the same user will be blocked until the previous ones release the lock on session. You also need to know that blocked requests do NOT form a queue and the order that they would each hold the lock is random. I thought you need to know this if you are to implement a PHP page with long execution time.

Comment: @swapnesh
Well, it takes 20 minutes. What I am doing is call the ajax function, and have it call the script that will do the heavy processing. This is why I am using AJAX, because it will be an asynchronous call that will allow me to return to the page while the script runs.

Answer (score 2):

No it will stop running.

You should be using a cron job instead to run a script that will take 20 minutes.

Dont forget to set the time limit to at least 20 minutes for that page!

Comment: Correct but I say something is wrong with the design. Who would wait for 20 minutes to get the response in the browser? Moreover refreshing/closing page will make this response inaccessible even if the script finally sends it.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo using a cronjob, you would typically be updating the database or something, not returning something to the browser. And a cron job cant be stopped by closing the browser!

Comment: from OP question `Also assume that I either refreshed or closed then opened the web page`, so don't tell me stories about cron jobs (I'm already using the scenario you talk about in my projects), as it's not the case.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo dunno what you're rambling on about!

Comment: easy bro :) Your answer is correct, useful (I've even upvoted it) especially for cron jobs as you state. But combined with OP description...I haven't heard for a long long long time about one who waits 20 minutes to see the page in the browser. Design problem I'm talking about is in OP project - not in your answer. Best regards!

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo sorry, misunderstood you. I was bascially telling him to scrap his design and use a cron job!

Comment: To clarify things. It is a job that is intiated by a back end process, this job updates the database and does a lot of heavy processing. So the page is NOT for the public, it is for admins who will run the job.

Answer (score 2):

> - Does my PHP script stop running?

Yes, PHP will cease execution if the browser disconnects (which it will on refresh/close). You can use `ignore_user_abort(true)` to prevent this, but I don't think that would be the best option for what you want.

> - If it keeps running, how can I force a response back to the page after it was refreshed?

No because the connection is gone, there is nothing to send a response back to. It would be more appropriate to invoke your long process as a background process when the ajax calls it, and immediately return a response, leaving the background process to work. You can use regular ajax calls to query if the process is complete (update a database for example on completion).

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php):

> The default behaviour is however for your script to be aborted when the remote client disconnects.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What if my script is on a separate file, would it cease execustion? I am going to test this senario with and without using ignore_user_abort();

Comment: Yes it will still cease execution by default. Be sure to pass `true` in `ignore_user_abort(true);`.